# EffiecientDet mAP evaluation on custom dataset

Tags: python, object-detection, evaluation, efficientnet

I'm trying to run 'mAP_evaluation.py' to get mAP evaluation on my own dataset:
https://github.com/Tessellate-Imaging/Monk_Object_Detection/tree/master/4_efficientdet/lib

but the whole python file is made for COCO dataset only I think, but if I use the function evaluate_coco() then I don't know how to customize my dataset to match the function. Please help.

P/S: I already trained and export the EfficientDet model (pth file), predicted test images/videos, just don't know how to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the issue like that

```
def __init__(root_dir, img_dir='images', set_dir='train2017', transform=None)
```

so I fixed right here from mAP_evaluation.py:

```
dataset_val = CocoDataset("/content/Monk_Object_Detection/4_efficientdet/lib/data/pothole", img_dir='images', set_dir='val2017',
                            transform=transforms.Compose([Normalizer(), Resizer()]))

evaluate_coco(dataset_val, efficientdet)
```